# New Line In Javascript Because Of PHP Include and Echo Of MySQL Query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a include statement that returns an echo to the browser of a single columns contents in a single found record.

It is returning a newline at the beginning of the record. This is breaking into two lines the javascript statement the echo is a part of.

This is the javascript statement:

```
var listname = '<?php include("test.php");?>';
```

test.php version 1:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $con);

$listref = $_GET["list"];

if(isset($listref)){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `Description` FROM `lists_management_index` WHERE `LL_ID` = '$listref'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "here we are";
    }
```

Generates:

```
var listname = ' 
here we are';
```

test.php version 2:

Generates:

```
var listname = 'here we are';
```

What is causing the line break and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks.

PS: Full test.php version 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['views']=1;
?>

<?php
include('../cons.php');

$db='lists';
include('../condb.php');

mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $con);

$listref = $_GET["list"];

if(isset($listref)){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `Description` FROM `lists_management_index` WHERE `LL_ID` = '$listref'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['Description'];
    }

include('../consc.php');
?>
```

Comment: PS - test.php version 1 originally had "echo $row['Description'];" where I now have echo "here we are"; but I replaced it for the purpose of testing that there was not a new line character associated with the records contents itself.

Comment: What is the source code for test.php version 2?

Comment: Be very very careful echoing DB results into JS like that. Just like with SQL, it's very easy to cause a JS injection hole. At bare mininum you shoul dhave something like `var listname = <?php echo json_encode_$row['Description'] ?>;` to ensure you're generating syntactically correct JS code.

Comment: hi @user824232 please also paste your code of version 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the beginning of your php script at `<?php`. Are these the very first characters of the file? Or is there any newline before that?

**Edit**: Based on the info that your comment provided I assume that the contents of `Description` for that row contain a newline at the start.

Comment: Full test.php version 1:
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['views']=1;
?>
 
<?php
include('../cons.php');

$db='lists';
include('../condb.php');

mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $con);

$listref = $_GET["list"];

if(isset($listref)){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT `Description` FROM `lists_management_index` WHERE `LL_ID` = '$listref'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 echo $row['Description'];
 }
 
include('../consc.php');
?>

Comment: I took that out of play by replacing ##echo $row['Description'];## with ## echo "we are here";###

Comment: Newline as you say. Was between two sets of PHP tags. Thanks!

Comment: A trailing newline in the included file, at the end, after ?> - was the problem for me..  Thanks.